# Same Command Over Several Lines in C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want to write a single variable over several lines in C++. more precisely in WINAPI.

Something like: (if \ is the command that does it,)

```
str=" This is a sample file trying to write multiple lines. \n but it is not same as line break. \
I am defining the same string over several lines. This is different from using backslash n. \
This is not supposed to print multipline in screen or in write file or on windows display. This\
is for ease of programming.";
```

The problem with this is that I got "|||" whereever I had used \ in my code. I don't want that to appear.
What shall I do?

Comment: yes! i can't delete it. but you guys can close it. Please do so!

Answer (score 6):

There are several alternatives. Here are two:

1. Put the content of the string into a file and read the file content into the string. When you find yourself using lots of long strings, this probably the “correct” way.
2. Use the following syntax:

   ```
   str = "This is a string that is going over several lines "
         "but it does not include line breaks and if you print "
         "the string you will see that it looks like it was "
         "written normally.";
   ```

   – C++ allows you to write several string literals after another and concatenates them automatically at compile time. That is, `"a" "b"` is the same as `"ab"`, as far as C++ is concerned.